# Good Design for adding business logic to Java Bean

Tags: java, compare, software-design, compareto

In the following code, does it make sense to have isMatched() in here (in a Value object/java bean)
? What's a good design. btw, I tried compareTo, compare, hashSet etc. by following other posts of Stack overflow and somehow that still does not work for me to remove dups from two lists.

```
public class SessionAttributes { 

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(SessionAttributes.class);

public SessionNotificationAttributes(String userName, String sessionState) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.sessionState = sessionState;
}

String userName;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
// .. getters/setters for sessionState

 public static isMatched (List<SessionAttributes> list1, 
             List<SessionAttributes> list2) {

   //.. custom logic here...
 }
```

}

==== Entire Code per the ask in comment by David. Look at main() method. This is directly copied pasted from Eclipse to meet http://sscce.org/  requirement ========

```
package snippet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class SessionAttributes  implements 
    Comparable<SessionAttributes>, Comparator<SessionAttributes>  {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(SessionAttributes.class);

public SessionAttributes(String userName, String sessionState) {
    /*
     * String nasPort, String endpointProfile, String audiSessionId, String
     * epsStatus, String securityGroup, String nasIp, String postureStatus,
     * String postureTimestamp) {
     */

    this.userName = userName;
    this.sessionState = sessionState;

    /*
     * this.nasPort = nasPort; this.endpoinProfile = endpointProfile;
     * this.auditSessionId = audiSessionId; this.epsStatus = epsStatus;
     * this.securityGroup = securityGroup; this.nasIp = nasIp;
     * this.postureStatus = postureStatus; this.postureTimestamp =
     * postureTimestamp;
     */

}


String userName;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
String sessionState;
public String getSessionState() {
    return sessionState;
}
public int compareTo(SessionAttributes o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (this.getUserName().equals(o.getUserName()) && this.getSessionState().equalsIgnoreCase(o.getSessionState())) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

public String toString() {

    return "\n User Name : " + this.getUserName() + " Session State : "
            + getSessionState() + "\n";
}



static boolean isMatched(List<SessionAttributes> list1,
        List<SessionAttributes> list2) {

    if (null == list1 || null == list2)
        return false;

    System.out.println("Actual List=>" + list1);
    System.out.println("Expected List=>" + list2);
    Iterator<SessionAttributes> iterator = list1.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SessionAttributes actual = iterator.next();
        Iterator<SessionAttributes> iterator2 = list2
                .iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            SessionAttributes expected = iterator2.next();
            if (expected.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    actual.getUserName())) {
                if (expected.getSessionState().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        actual.getSessionState())) {
                    System.out.println("Element matched - user name-"
                            + expected.getUserName() + " State -"
                            + expected.getSessionState());
                    iterator.remove();
                    iterator2.remove();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element NOT matched - user name-"
                        + expected.getUserName() + " State -"
                        + expected.getSessionState());

            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Lists after removing Dups -");
    System.out.println("list1 =>" + list1.toString() + " list2 -"
            + list2.toString());

    if (list1.size() > 0 || list2.size() > 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

static void sortLists () {

    List<SessionAttributes> expectedSessionList = new ArrayList<SessionAttributes>();

    SessionAttributes user11 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "STARTED"); //
    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    SessionAttributes user12 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

    SessionAttributes user13 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser5", "STARTED");

    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    expectedSessionList.add(user11);
    expectedSessionList.add(user12);
    expectedSessionList.add(user13);

    List<SessionAttributes> actualSessionList = new ArrayList<SessionAttributes>();

    SessionAttributes user3 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "STARTED");
    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    SessionAttributes user4 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

    SessionAttributes user5 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser2", "DISCONNECTED");

    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    actualSessionList.add(user3);
    actualSessionList.add(user4);
    actualSessionList.add(user5);

    Set<SessionAttributes> removeDups = new HashSet<SessionAttributes>();

    boolean b1 = removeDups.add(user11);
    boolean b2 = removeDups.add(user12);
    boolean b3 = removeDups.add(user13);
    boolean b4 = removeDups.add(user3);
    boolean b5 = removeDups.add(user4);
    boolean b6 = removeDups.add(user5);
    System.out.println(" Set--" + removeDups);

    // removeDups.addAll(expectedSessionList);
    // removeDups.addAll(actualSessionList);

    System.out.println("== Printing Set ====");
    int countMisMatch = 0;

    System.out.println(isMatched(actualSessionList, expectedSessionList));

    // int isMatch = user3.compareTo(user1);
    // System.out.println("Compare=>" + isMatch);
}

static void  sortSet () {

    List<SessionAttributes> expectedSessionList = new ArrayList<SessionAttributes>();

    SessionAttributes user11 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "STARTED"); //
    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    SessionAttributes user12 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

    SessionAttributes user13 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser5", "STARTED");

    SessionAttributes user3 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "STARTED");
    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    SessionAttributes user4 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

    SessionAttributes user5 = new SessionAttributes(
            "postureuser2", "DISCONNECTED");

    // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);


    Set<SessionAttributes> removeDups = new HashSet<SessionAttributes>();

    boolean b1 = removeDups.add(user11);
    boolean b2 = removeDups.add(user12);
    boolean b3 = removeDups.add(user13);
    boolean b4 = removeDups.add(user3);
    boolean b5 = removeDups.add(user4);
    boolean b6 = removeDups.add(user5);
    System.out.println(" Set--" + removeDups);

    // removeDups.addAll(expectedSessionList);
    // removeDups.addAll(actualSessionList);

    System.out.println("== Printing Set ====");
    System.out.println(removeDups);

    // int isMatch = user3.compareTo(user1);
    // System.out.println("Compare=>" + isMatch);



}

public int compare(SessionAttributes o1,
        SessionAttributes o2) {

    LOGGER.debug("Compare called -[" + o1.getUserName() + "] ["
            + o2.getUserName() + "]");
    boolean isSameUserName = o1.userName.equalsIgnoreCase(o2.userName);
    boolean isSameState = o1.sessionState
            .equalsIgnoreCase(this.sessionState);

    if (isSameUserName && isSameState)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}

public boolean equals(SessionAttributes obj) {

    if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof SessionAttributes)) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println(" In equals==");
    boolean isSameUserName = obj.userName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.userName);
    boolean isSameState = obj.sessionState
            .equalsIgnoreCase(this.sessionState);
    return (isSameUserName && isSameState);
}

public int hashCode() {

    System.out.println(" in hashcode ");
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 17 + this.getUserName().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + this.getSessionState().hashCode();
    // hash = hash * 13 + this.getAuditSessionId().hashCode();
    System.out.println(" hash=>" + hash);
    return hash;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //sortSet();
    sortLists();
}
```

}

==== Code from David which is supposed to remove dups. Pasting only relevant portion for better comparison. Somehow, this still does not work

```
    public int compareTo(SessionAttributesFromDavid o) {
          if (this == o) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Null is considered less than any object.
        if (o == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Use compareToIgnoreCase since you used equalsIgnoreCase in equals.

        int diff = userName.compareToIgnoreCase(o.userName);
        if (diff != 0)
            return diff;

        diff = sessionState.compareToIgnoreCase(o.sessionState);
        return diff;
    }
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // See if o is the same object. If it is, return true.
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        // The instanceof check also checks for null. If o is null, instanceof will be false.
        if (!(o instanceof SessionAttributes)) {
            return false;
        }

        SessionAttributes that = (SessionAttributes) o;
        return userName.equalsIgnoreCase(that.userName) &&   sessionState.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionState);
    }
```

Set removeDups = new TreeSet();

```
        boolean b1 = removeDups.add(user11);
        boolean b2 = removeDups.add(user12);
        boolean b3 = removeDups.add(user13);
        boolean b4 = removeDups.add(user3);
        boolean b5 = removeDups.add(user4);
        boolean b6 = removeDups.add(user5);

        System.out.println(" Set--" + removeDups);
```

Set--[
 User Name : postureuser2 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser5 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not create an isMatched method to compare two Lists of SessionAttributes.

I would definitely go with having SessionAttributes implement equals and hashCode. It's crucial that you implement them both and in the same way. If you want to compare both Strings for equality, calculate your hashCode using both Strings. If you don't get equals and hashCode right, none of this will work.

If you want to put SessionAttributes in a SortedSet, I would have SessionAttributes implement Comparable, too.

Also, I would make SessionAttributes immutable, so no setters and declare the two String elements as final. If you do this, you can add SessionAttributes to a Set or Map and you won't have to worry about their values changing. If you don't make them immutable, you have to be sure not to change any of the SessionAttributes values after adding them to the List or Set.

Instead of putting them in a List, I would put them in a Set to ensure that you don't have duplicates within the same Collection of SessionAttributes.

If you want to remove duplicates from one of the Collections, use Collection's removeAll method on it, passing it the other Collection of SessionAttributes.

As a side note, sessionState looks like a variable with a finite number of possible values, so I would consider defining an Enum for it instead of making it a String.

I hope this helps.

Edit:

Your compareTo method is not working because it returns 0 if equal, but -1 if not.
It does not fulfill the contract for compareTo. Please read its [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

Below is the SSCCE with some changes and comments. Since in equals, you compare for equality ignoring case, you have to convert the Strings to all upper or lower case in your hashCode method so it will be consistent with equals. You also have to use compareIgnoreCase in your compareTo method for consistency.
Since the compareTo method works, you now can simply use a TreeSet to sort a collection of your objects.

I removed the methods you won't need any more and tried to put some helpful comments in the code.

```
package snippet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

// You don't need to implement Comparator.
public class SessionAttributes implements Comparable<SessionAttributes> {

    // You typically define member variables at the top of the class definition.
    private final String userName;
    private final String sessionState;

    public SessionAttributes(String userName, String sessionState) {

        // Throw a NullPointerException from the constructor if either of the Strings is null. This way, you know that
        // if the object is constructed successfully, it is free of nulls.
        if (userName == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("userName must not be null");
        }
        if (sessionState == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("sessionState must not be null");
        }
        /*
         * String nasPort, String endpointProfile, String audiSessionId, String epsStatus, String securityGroup, String
         * nasIp, String postureStatus, String postureTimestamp) {
         */

        this.userName = userName;
        this.sessionState = sessionState;

        /*
         * this.nasPort = nasPort; this.endpoinProfile = endpointProfile; this.auditSessionId = audiSessionId;
         * this.epsStatus = epsStatus; this.securityGroup = securityGroup; this.nasIp = nasIp; this.postureStatus =
         * postureStatus; this.postureTimestamp = postureTimestamp;
         */

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getSessionState() {
        return sessionState;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SessionAttributes o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return 0;
        }
        // Null is considered less than any object.
        if (o == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Use compareToIgnoreCase since you used equalsIgnoreCase in equals.

        int diff = userName.compareToIgnoreCase(o.userName);
        if (diff != 0)
            return diff;

        diff = sessionState.compareToIgnoreCase(o.sessionState);
        return diff;
    }

    // public int compareTo(SessionAttributes o) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // if (this.getUserName().equals(o.getUserName()) && this.getSessionState().equalsIgnoreCase(o.getSessionState())) {
    // return 0;
    // }
    // return -1;
    // }

    public String toString() {

        return "\n User Name : " + this.getUserName() + " Session State : " + getSessionState() + "\n";
    }

    // public boolean equals(SessionAttributes obj) {
    //
    // if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof SessionAttributes)) {
    // return false;
    // }
    // System.out.println(" In equals==");
    // boolean isSameUserName = obj.userName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.userName);
    // boolean isSameState = obj.sessionState.equalsIgnoreCase(this.sessionState);
    // return (isSameUserName && isSameState);
    // }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // See if o is the same object. If it is, return true.
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        // The instanceof check also checks for null. If o is null, instanceof will be false.
        if (!(o instanceof SessionAttributes)) {
            return false;
        }

        SessionAttributes that = (SessionAttributes) o;
        return userName.equalsIgnoreCase(that.userName) && sessionState.equalsIgnoreCase(sessionState);
    }

    public int hashCode() {

        System.out.println(" in hashcode ");
        int hash = 1;
        // Since in equals you are comparing for equality and ignoring case, you must convert the Strings to either
        // lower
        // or upper case when computing the hashCode so that it will always be consistent with equals.
        hash = hash * 17 + this.getUserName().toUpperCase().hashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + this.getSessionState().toUpperCase().hashCode();
        // hash = hash * 13 + this.getAuditSessionId().hashCode();
        System.out.println(" hash=>" + hash);
        return hash;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sortSet();
        // sortLists();

        // expectedSessionList
        List<SessionAttributes> expectedSessionList = new ArrayList<SessionAttributes>();

        SessionAttributes user11 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser1", "STARTED"); //
        // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        SessionAttributes user12 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

        SessionAttributes user13 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser5", "STARTED");

        expectedSessionList.add(user11);
        expectedSessionList.add(user12);
        expectedSessionList.add(user13);

        System.out.println("expectedSessionList: " + expectedSessionList);

        // actualSessionList
        List<SessionAttributes> actualSessionList = new ArrayList<SessionAttributes>();

        SessionAttributes user3 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser1", "STARTED");
        // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        SessionAttributes user4 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser1", "DISCONNECTED");

        SessionAttributes user5 = new SessionAttributes("postureuser2", "DISCONNECTED");

        // ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        actualSessionList.add(user3);
        actualSessionList.add(user4);
        actualSessionList.add(user5);

        System.out.println("actualSessionList: " + actualSessionList);

        // removeDups
        // Use a TreeSet to sort it.
        Set<SessionAttributes> removeDups = new TreeSet<SessionAttributes>();

        boolean b1 = removeDups.add(user11);
        boolean b2 = removeDups.add(user12);
        boolean b3 = removeDups.add(user13);
        boolean b4 = removeDups.add(user3);
        boolean b5 = removeDups.add(user4);
        boolean b6 = removeDups.add(user5);

        System.out.println(" Set--" + removeDups);

        actualSessionList.removeAll(expectedSessionList);
        System.out.println("actualSessionList after removeAll: " + actualSessionList);

    }

}
```

Output:

expectedSessionList: [
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser5 Session State : STARTED
]

actualSessionList: [
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser2 Session State : DISCONNECTED
]

Set--[
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser2 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser5 Session State : STARTED
]

actualSessionList after removeAll: [
 User Name : postureuser2 Session State : DISCONNECTED
]

Comment: thanks for your comments. I did implement equals and hashCode. I did not paste the entire code. Good point on removing setters. I did try comparable, comparator, adding objects to Set, HashSet but somehow it did not work for me. I wanted two value match like userName=user1, sessionState=disconnected in two lists. Somehow Set etc did not work for me. There were posts related to this here on SO which I followed but did not work. Not sure if getters/setters caused that. let me try removing setters/getters and try Set/removaAll approach.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, please update your question with a short, self-contained, compilable example. [http://sscce.org/](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Actually, above code was aimed for SSCCE. Let me get the entire code and you can suggest what could be missing. I gave up on Comparator and went brute force way (Iterating over list of session beans to find a match using equals)

Comment: Thanks, David. Did you test it ? It seems similar to what I pasted. Thanks much for spending your time on this. Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, yes I tested it. It works. You're welcome. The stackoverflow way of saying thank you is to approve an answer. If you feel I answered your question to your satisfaction, please approve it. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not accept this as the answer? You said in your question that you could not get "compareTo, compare, hashSet etc." to work. I posted a change to your example with a working compareTo, equals and hashCode. I explained what I did to make the methods work. It means you don't have to implement your own code to sort or compare for matches. It is similar to the code you pasted, but not the same in that the compareTo, equals, and hashCode works. Did you test what I gave you?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, compiled it and ran it after removing Lists versions (retained only TreeSet.add (SessionAttribute) and it still prints everything and does not drop the duplicates. Please note my final goal is to drop duplicates. In this case, I would like Set to be empty 

Set--[
 User Name : postureuser2 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser5 Session State : STARTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
, 
 User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
]

Comment: I added my output.

expectedSessionList and actualSessionList shared:

User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED
User Name : postureuser1 Session State : DISCONNECTED
After calling removeAll on actualSessionList those two are removed from actualSessionList.

Where are your duplicates?

Comment: I took the code that builds the removeDups Set directly from YOUR code. NO objects that get added to the removDups Set are duplicates. Look at YOUR definition of equals/hashCode. You compare both userName and sessionState. All the objects you added in the removeDups Set are different from each other. If you want to see duplicates get removed, either change your definition of equals and hashCode (compare only userName for example), OR try adding two SessionAttributes objects that are duplicates by YOUR definition of equals/hashCode (The userName and sessionState must be equal, ignoring case).

Comment: So, actualSessionList:User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED  expectedSessionList:User Name : postureuser1 Session State : STARTED

Comment: You are right actually. Let me vote up. Thanks for your time. Could you please Vote up my question since we both had to go back and forth to analyze this.

Comment: Thanks, @David ! Actually, if I there is a match or dups, then I would like to remove this entry from both Lists, in that case, I was using iterator.remove() from lists (Until this Set worked)- what would you do ? Reason I want to do this is - at the end of this comparison, I would pass my test if the final Set comes out as Empty. Which means all dups are gone since I know my expected values. Basically, if all of expected values are in Actual values, just make it empty. Removing dups are still retaining expected. This would prevent the code to iterate Set again and probably make it faster !

Comment: removeAll is the method you need. If you call removeAll on Collection A and pass Collection B, removeAll will remove all the objects from A that were in B. A would only have objects that were not also in B. A and B would have only unique objects. B would still have the same objects, but you know that none of those objects are in A because removeAll removes the duplicates. The only way removeAll would result in an empty Collection (List, Set, etc.), is if the Collection you passed in removeAll had the exact same values. For this to work, your equals and hashCode must be right. That's the key.

Comment: If you want to have a Collection of all objects that are unique to Collection A and Collection B, you could make a copy of Collection A before calling removeAll on it. Then, call removeAll on Collection B, passing it the COPY of Collection A. Finally, you would call addAll on Collection A, passing it Collection B. Or, you could use [Common Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) The disjunction method sounds like it does what you need.